# How can I parameterize a module so that it can configure the applications that require it on demand?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module

On the pattern of a [harvested framework](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/HarvestedFramework.html), I want to factorize my AngularJS applications' configurations and utilities into a standalone module, for example:

```
angular.module("configurer", [])
.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/hal+json";

}]);
```

Then, in my applications:

```
angular.module("app", ["configurer"]);
```

---

I would like to add an **optional** CSRF protection:

```
angular.module("configurer", [])
.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/hal+json";

  if (applicationWantsCsrfProtection) {
    // implement CSRF protection
  }

}]);
```

**The question is**, how to set this `applicationWantsCsrfProtection` variable?

---

I tried to go through constants:

```
angular.module("configurer", [])
.config(["$injector", "$httpProvider", function($injector, $httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/hal+json";

  if ($injector.has("Application")) {
    var Application = $injector.get("Application");
    if (Application.hasOwnProperty("CSRF")) {
      // implement CSRF protection with Application.CSRF.* attributes
    }
  }

}]);
```

Then, in my applications:

```
angular.module("app", ["configurer"])
.constant("Application", {
  CSRF: {
    headerName: "X-CSRF-TOKEN",
    cookieName: "APP-CSRF-TOKEN"
  }
});
```

But `$injector.has("Application")` always returns `false`, no matter if the `Application` constant is defined in the applications or not:

http://plnkr.co/edit/8RFwqvs6Tmp9gpGkUq7W?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution through a provider:

```js
(function(angular) {

  var config = function($injector) {
    console.log("configurer config has Application: " + $injector.has("Application")); // true
  };

  var run = function($injector) {
    console.log("configurer run has Application: " + $injector.has("Application")); // true
  };

  angular.module("configurer", [])

  .provider("init", function() {
    return {
      config: config,
      $get: function() {
        return {
          run: run
        }
      }
    }
  });

})(angular);
```

Then, in an application:

```js
angular.module("app", ["configurer"])

  .constant("Application", {
    CSRF: {
      headerName: "X-CSRF-TOKEN",
      cookieName: "APP-CSRF-TOKEN"
    }
  })

  .config(function(initProvider, $injector) {
    initProvider.config($injector);
  })

  .run(function(init, $injector) {
    init.run($injector);
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/c301t8TN8TfWcn52Kit2?p=info

---

One advantage of this solution is that configurer submodules may extend the configurer behavior without modifying applications:

```js
(function(angular) {

  var config = function($injector) {
    console.log("subConfigurer config has Application: " + $injector.has("Application")); // true
  };

  var run = function($injector) {
    console.log("subConfigurer run has Application: " + $injector.has("Application")); // true
  };

  angular.module("subConfigurer", ["configurer"])

  .config(function(initProvider) {

    var configCallfront = initProvider.config;    
    initProvider.config = function($injector) {
      configCallfront($injector);
      config($injector);
    };

    var runCallfront = initProvider.$get().run;
    initProvider.$get = function() {
      return {
        run: function($injector) {
          runCallfront($injector);
          run($injector);
        }
      }
    };

  });

})(angular);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GQKcMK7RkTEwK0YEfAiW?p=info

---

Still open to criticisms or better solutions though!